# Unity procedural mesh generation

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, mesh

Here is code for generating triangles,vertices are loaded from a file directly :

```
        int n = 10;
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[n * 2];
        int vC = 0;

        int[] tri = new int[6 * (n - 1)];

        int tC = 0;


        for(int i=0;i<2*(n-1);i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                tri[tC++] = i;
                tri[tC++] = i + 2;
                tri[tC++] = i + 1;

             }
            else
            {
                tri[tC++] = i;
                tri[tC++] = i + 1;
                tri[tC++] = i + 2;
            }
        }
```

Vertices are loaded from a file.

And here is a result :

tri 0 2 1

tri 1 2 3

tri 2 4 3

tri 3 4 5

tri 4 6 5

tri 5 6 7

tri 6 8 7

tri 7 8 9

tri 8 10 9

tri 9 10 11

tri 10 12 11

tri 11 12 13

tri 12 14 13

tri 13 14 15

tri 14 16 15

tri 15 16 17

tri 16 18 17

tri 17 18 19

vertex (1707.8, 0.0, 1707.8)

vertex (1708.0, 0.0, 1708.0)

vertex (1708.1, 0.0, 1708.1)

vertex (1707.8, 0.0, 1707.8)

vertex (1707.8, 0.0, 1707.8)

vertex (1708.1, 0.0, 1708.1)

vertex (1708.2, 0.0, 1708.2)

vertex (1707.8, 0.0, 1707.8)

vertex (1708.1, 0.0, 1708.1)

vertex (1708.0, 0.0, 1708.0)

vertex (1708.1, 0.0, 1708.1)

vertex (1708.2, 0.0, 1708.2)

vertex (1708.2, 0.0, 1708.2)

vertex (1708.2, 0.0, 1708.2)

vertex (1708.0, 0.0, 1708.0)

vertex (1708.6, 0.0, 1708.6)

vertex (1708.5, 0.0, 1708.5)

vertex (1708.2, 0.0, 1708.2)

vertex (1708.5, 0.0, 1708.5)

vertex (1708.4, 0.0, 1708.4)

Can anyone tell me why it is not rendering anything.

Comment: Looks at first sight that the difference is that small (and shifted in the X and Z) direction, so the result might be too small, or "outside the frustum".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a mesh renderer into a game object and setup the vertices and triangles into it.

Check this [link](http://studentgamedev.blogspot.com/2013/08/unity-voxel-tutorial-part-1-generating.html) to see how you can generate mesh by code.